# Adding .so to Xamarin android binding library

Tags: android, jar, xamarin, shared-libraries

I have a xamarin android project (VS2015) which I added a Android bindings library project to to use a java lib. The wrapper works fine and I can call the classes/methods in my application project. However one of the java classes depends on

armeabi/libjnisgfplib.so

I have tried adding to both /Assets and /libs within my application. BuildAction = AndroidNativeLibrary, Copy = Always. Yet it can't find the lib and I keep getting.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjnisgfplib.so"

I have tried `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("libjnisgfplib");`before calling the class but I receive the same exeption.

How can I add libjnisgfplib.so to my project so the binding library jar can find it?

Comment: Is the .so within `/lib/` or is it nested inside `/lib/arm/`? In my experience, you need to place the .so file within one of the binary folders (`arm`, `x86` etc) for it to resolve.

Comment: it's within lib/armeabi/ I've also tried arm/ x86/ armeabi-v7a etc.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Next step is to remote into the device and locate where the `.so` file is: `adb shell` -> `run-as com.company-1`. Explore around in the applications folder. Maybe that will hold some clues?

Answer (score 2):

So it's a total mastery to me why this worked but changing the name from

> libjnisgfplib.so **to** jnisgfplib.so

worked. I am assuming something about it being lib/libjnis was throwing it off, but lib/jnis is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining your .so file as an AndroidNativeLibrary using armeabi?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="path/to/libjnisgfplib.so">
        <Abi>armeabi</Abi>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
</ItemGroup>
```

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `libs\armeabi-v7a\libjnisgfplib.so`. It solved the same problem I was having.