# Xamarin Forms, UnsatisfiedLinkError can't find .so file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have exhausted by Google searches trying to solve this problem, so I beg for your help :). I am trying to integrate a third party SDK (bluetooth diagnostic adapter) into a Xamarin Forms cross platform project. They give example Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects to use as a template and those both work fine. In my Xamarin Forms app the iOS project works fine and I can connect, the Android project throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError on this line:
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("nblr32");
In the Android project I have a lib folder with armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a subfolders. Inside each are the appropriate .so files (including libnblr32.so) provided by the bluetooth manufacturer. Each .so file has been correctly set for build action of AndroidNativeLibrary.
If I catch the error on the device the exception message is:
"Library nblr32 not found; tried [/system/lib64/libnblr32.so, /system/vendor/lib64/libnblr32.so]".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have inspected the APK and all the .so files are there, the LoadLibrary just doesn't seem to find them or is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Is that an arm64 or x86_64 device you are testing on?

Comment: It's an Arm64 (old Oneplus 2).

Comment: Is it emulator or actual device?

Comment: Create folder for x86 x64 armeabi as well https://github.com/pmahend1/Xamarin/issues/1 see screenshots here.

Comment: Actual device. As stated in the original post I do have the folder structure correct and build action correct. And also the example dedicated Xamarin.Android project works correctly, it just has this issue when converted to Xamarin Forms. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have used the app Native Library Monitor to ensure they are present in the APK. I would attach that text file but I don't see a way to do that, and it is too long to paste into a comment.

Comment: Whats the ABI of the device? Are you running it in debug mode by connecting to laptop? Whats your android project csproj looks like? Whats the Android version ?Whats the Xamarin forms version?

Comment: Device is Arm64 Android 9, developing on Visual Studio Mac (8.8). Have tried it in debug connected to Mac, and also installing from debug and release APKs. Where should the .so files be installed to on the device? Can I check for them without having root?

Comment: can't copy all of .csproj but here are some relevant parts:                                                             <AndroidSupportedAbis>arm64-v8a;armeabi-v7a</AndroidSupportedAbis>                               <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="lib\arm64-v8a\libnblr32.so" />                                               <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="lib\armeabi-v7a\libnblr32.so" />

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Try to change the name of .so file,refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210093/10768653).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but that doesn't work either. I get the same error even after renaming:                                                                                                                                                          "Library nblr32 not found; tried [/system/lib64/libnblr32.so, /system/vendor/lib64/libnblr32.so]"

Comment: What's the name of folder which you add the .so files ? `lib` or `libs` ?

Comment: I have tried both, it is currently back to "lib".

Comment: I look at the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries),and in its sample,it use the folder named `libs`.

Comment: What I don't get is when I inspect the application with Native Library Monitor the libraries ARE installed. But my app can't find them. Is there a way to post attachments here?

Comment: You could share a link(Remember to erase your personal information).

Comment: In case someone in the future with the same issue stumbles upon this I thought I would follow up. In my case I am using an interface from Forms to platform. My load library call was in this interface. After much trial and error I got it to work by changing my call to "Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("NameOfLibrary"));